# HTML CSS styling for a fixed div and a flexible div

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following layout where there are two columns, a fixed size one (50px wide) for my icon and a flexible one that stretches the remaining part for my messages. I am using bootstrap 4 with angular2

[image: sketch]

Currently, I am using the following setup with bootstrap 4 grid layout

```
<div class="col-1">
    <md-icon class="material-icons notification-row-icon">done</md-icon>
</div>

<div class="col-11">
    <div class="notification-row-text-div">
        <label class="notification-mrow-essage-label">{{message}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the output is off when the screen is extra small as shown below. I want the icon to be always on the left hand side of the message rather than stacked when the screen gets small. Since the col way seems to create this problem, I am thinking to re-build this from good old html/css way instead. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Problem is : what do you want your layout to do when content become too large than available width ?

Comment: Is it necessary to place the icon in its own column to begin with?

Comment: When the the text is long, I want the text to break at space or be 'wrapped' such that the container height grows. Reason for the icon to be in its own column is to show clearly an icon column and a message column. I have updated the image to demonstrate what I am looking to achieve. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [`flexbox`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties) solution.

The main property to know in this solution is [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).

> It specifies what amount of space inside the flex container the item should take up.

If all items in a flex container had the same value, they'd all be the same width. If only one item like we have in this example has `flex-grow` applied, it takes up the remaining space of it's container.

If you're unfamiliar with [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and the value `border-box`, it includes padding and borders with an elements width assignment instead of them being added in addition to the assigned width. So if you tell and element to be 200px wide and have 10px of padding, it's 200px wide. Not 220px.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.col {
  padding: 5px;
}
.col.fixed {
  width: 50px;
}
.col.fill {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col fixed">
      <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="col fill">
      <p>
        Bring a spring upon her cable handsomely gibbet Corsair scuttle prow Buccaneer nipper. Gun jack clap of thunder port holystone killick bilge water chandler. Gunwalls Cat o'nine tails lookout careen Jack Tar salmagundi boom mutiny.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me best. I had to change col and row to my-col and my-row so bootstrap 4 does not effect it. I like how it does not use bootstrap 4 at all.

Comment: The code was a generic example. As others have pointed out, Bootstrap 4 comes with flexbox and a column class with the same name as my example `.col`, which also uses `flex-grow: 1`. I'm guessing the main reason you don't want to use Bootstrap's `.row` and `.col` classes is that you want a different margin/padding than the default 15px. If you're going to continue to use Bootstrap 4 I might overwrite those values to the desired ones. Then just make a custom class to set a specific width on your desired column. You could build your own copy with SASS.

Comment: I am thinking there is more to that though. My old method with col-1 and col-11, even thought the documentation says that it should not stack at all (unlike col-md-1), it did in my case. However, when I used your setup, it works beautifully. So I am thinking there is more than just padding and margin difference. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen where it docs say it shouldn't stack. That kind of goes against what a responsive grid should do, which is start stacking at various breakpoints. If you need those breakpoints (media queries) in other parts of your app but not in a specific portion, then custom classes might be the best approach.

Comment: There are util classes to remove the padding too (`p-0`). I don't understand @ErnieKev why ask about Bootstrap 4 at all if you're not going to utilize it?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4 for most of my app and it works great. It is just this specific case writing it from plane old css html gives me no surprises. I'm sure there is a bootstrap 4 solution. To me it seems like col-1 and col-11 still stacks when the screen size is super small like my case. There might be a way to turn it off?

Comment: The cols stack eventually because of padding, but as I said the padding can be removed. Anyway using col-1 & col-11 isn't the best approach with Bootstrap 4 since you want a fixed width column. That's why just `col` would work better in BS4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox`

```css
.flexbox{
  display:flex;
}
.col-1,
.col-11{
  border:1px solid;
}
.col-1 {
    width: 50px;
}
.col-11 {
    flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=flexbox>
  <div class="col-1">
    <md-icon class="material-icons notification-row-icon">done</md-icon>
  </div>

  <div class="col-11">
    <div class="notification-row-text-div">
      <label class="notification-mrow-essage-label">{{message}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this without multiple columns...

```css
.icon {
  width: 3em; /* change as you need */
  display: inline-block;
}

.notification-row-text-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <span class="icon">&#9635;</span>
      <div class="notification-row-text-div">
        <label class="notification-mrow-essage-label">John Doe</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is built into Bootstrap 4 so you don't need any extra CSS other than the fixed width column.

```
.fixed {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Then just use the auto-layout `col` class to consume the remaining space:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="fixed">
            icon
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            ..
        </div>
</div>
```

The `col` class already uses flex-grow.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/iprwiDJhgy

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple code. It is fully tested. I hope it will help you.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col fixed">
      <span>&copy;</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col fill">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.col.fixed {
  width:50px;
  float:left;
}
.col.fill {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
</style>
```